# SCCP restrictions in Mobile Networks

Tags: mobile, routes, ss7

I'm curious about what access and routing restrictions are typically imposed upon SCCP in mobile networks.

Just a few questions I'd appreciate some help with:

Does Global title translation in practice allow traffic between any two nodes?
If not, could this be done if you had the point code of the destination node?

Can any node perform a title analysis?

Can any geographical information be inferred from a point code?